# CSS height property is acting wierd

Tags: html, css, height

I have a div inside a div, but when I set the height and width to the div, there is a problem with the height. Its easier to just show you my problem.

Here is my code:

```css
.prodContent1 {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #e1e1e1;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 300px;
 z-index: 1;
 display: none;
}
.prod-div {
 background-color: grey;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px; 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="prodContent1" id="prodCont1">
    <div class="prod-div">
    </div>
 
</div>
```

As you can see, im setting the width and hight to be the same, and therefor expect the div to be a cube. But when I look in the browser, this is what i see: (It's the small, grey box)

[image: The grey box is the div]

I cant figure out why it gets this tall. I even tried setting the hight to 1px, and using a measurment tool on the browser, i found out that it was acutaly 4 times the hight i set.
(Dont worry about the display:none, this is a drop-down div).

Anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: Please make sure your div is not inheriting any other CSS properties. Use the google chrome dev tools to inspect the element and search its styles. I tested this code in a JSFiddle and it works as expected.

Comment: its possible if there are four div with `.prod-div` class

Comment: You are absolutely right Bhuwan. I just figured it out, hehe.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localised and will be of no use to anyone else in future

Comment: How do I close it?

Answer (score 1):

the code you posted here is ok (excepting the display: none;, which is making it invisible for us) so the issue may be on some other part of your code:

```css
.prodContent1 {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #e1e1e1;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 300px;
 z-index: 1;
}
.prod-div {
 background-color: grey;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px; 
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="prodContent1" id="prodCont1">
    <div class="prod-div">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had four divs with the same class, and therefor they all added up underneath each other, making a tall square. Stupid mistake, my fault.

Comment: lol, you shouldn't add an answer if there's no code issue, mark the answer that sais there's an issue on some other part of your code
" and delete this one, adding a comment explaining it, in order other users can find the solution.